# I want to simply copy the file by executing xcopy command using groovy

Tags: groovy, xcopy

I want to copy a file whose source and destinations are stored in variables.

```
def  gitPath = 'C:\\demo1\\'
def  ServerPath= 'D:\\demo\\git1\\' 
def  file = 'Sports/Badminton/Players/Saina.txt'
def  command = "xcopy /y $gitPath$file $ServerPath$file /Q"

def copyManuscriptsCommandExecute =command.execute();

def cmcErr = new StringBuffer()
copyManuscriptsCommandExecute.consumeProcessErrorStream(cmcErr)

  def copyManuscriptsCommandExecuteOutput=copyManuscriptsCommandExecute.text
        println "Copy Manuscripts Command Execution Output: "+copyManuscriptsCommandExecuteOutput
        println "Copy Manuscripts Command Execution Error: "+cmcErr.toString()
```

I am getting error as invalid parameters.IF I use `def file = 'Sports\\Badminton\\Players\\Saina.txt'` then it is working fine.However i am getting the value of variable file from the output of a command execution so i can't change that. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You need to convert unix path separator to windows like \\.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my question ..if file ='Sports\\Badminton\\Players\\Saina.txt' then it is working fine...@aristotll

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. See my answer below.

Comment: Don't use `"Some String".execute()` - it will sooner or later fail with a whitepace in an argument.  Use `["some", "string"].execute()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert unix path separator to windows like \.

```
 ...

 file = normalize(file)
 def command = "xcopy /y $gitPath$file $ServerPath$file /Q"
...
static String normalize(String s) {
    s.replaceAll('/', File.separator)
}
```

Just normalize the separator before using the string read from command line.

Comment: It is throwing compilation error as Method definition not expected here. Please define the method at an appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead.

Comment: @rohit.dagur Just move the method upper before where it is called or simple use `file.replaceAll('/', File.separator)`.

Comment: exception thrown-groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static example.normalize() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Sports/Badminton/Players/Saina.txt] it is because of file = normalize(file)

Comment: It seems your file type is a List? Can you show your full code? From your problem I expect your file is a String object.

Comment: I AM GETTING VARIABLE 'file' From .... b.readLines().collect() { it.split(' ')[4].split('\t') as List }.each 
      
          { action, file   ->

Comment: file = file.replace("/","\\")...it worked for me...Thanks..@aristotll